# Create a tinyMCE custom button that opens a Bootstrap Modal window instead of the tinyMCE default

Tags: tinymce

I have successfully created a custom button that opens a pop-up which works by opening the native tinyMCE modal window.

Following the instructions in the "Adding popup after clicking" section of https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-custom-buttons#tmce-section-2

Id like to have the more elegant bootstrap modal window used instead. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in that article, you can add your own custom toolbar buttons to TinyMCE.  Instead of using the WindowManager in TinyMCE you call call whatever JavaScript you like.

You would need something like this in your init:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('customButton', {
        text: 'Custom Button',
        icon: false,   //you can use an image instead of text
        onclick: function () {
            // JavaScript code to open your Bootstrap modal
            // The modal would use TinyMCE APIs to write data back into the editor
        }
    });
}
```

In addition to that code you will need to also add the following to your init to add the button to the toolbar:

```
toolbar2: "... customButton ...",
```